# Como hacer uso de un navbar en todos los .html de mi proyecto

Tags: html, c#, .net, navbar

Estoy desarrollando un navbar ubicado en el pie de pagina el cual se encargara de mostrar un aviso de cookies, como son varias paginas (archivos `.html`) que contiene mi proyecto quisiera replicar este navbar en todos los archivos `.html` de mi proyecto, sin tener que agregarlo uno por uno.

El siguiente es el código de mi navbar que tengo ubicado en mi index.html:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="cookie_consent_user_accepted" class="alert alert-infoCookie alert-dismissible fade in navbar-fixed-bottom hide" role="alert" style="margin-bottom: -1px; font-family: Lettera Text Std;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>     
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <h4>Titulo del aviso</h4>
                <p>Aquí va el contenido del aviso </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="display: grid;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-cookie" data-dismiss="alert">Aceptar</button>
                <br/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-cookie" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Revisar</button>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Como ven el anterior va a ser un aviso para uso de cookies así es que requiero utilizarlo en todos los archivos `.html` de mi proyecto.

Adicional a esto estoy haciendo uso en mi pagina web de **.NET** y **C#**

Comment: No podrás hacerlo de manera automática sin hacer uso de un lenguaje de programación del lado del servidor ¿puedes usar alguno?

Comment: @anythingg Estoy haciendo uso de C# y .NET

Comment: porque no implementas un layout?

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco Puedes apoyarme por favor con un ejemplo en una respuesta para darle validez

Comment: Que tipo de proyecto es? mvc? en MVC puedes utilizar layouts que seria lo equivalente a master pages en asp.net... dime tu proyecot es de MVC? o que tipo de proyecto tienes para el front?

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco En este caso el proyecto no es MVC